# customizing VSC formatting on Save

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an existing PHP codebase where methods are formatted:

```
public function myIssue() {
    // some code...
}
```

VSC changes this on save to:

```
public function myIssue() 
{
    // some code...
}
```

Is there some way I can turn off this specific VSC formatting rule from occurring on save and allow all the other formatting changes VSC suggests to still occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the answer you are looking for but an explanation from vscode's perspective:

Visual studio code is implementing what is called a PSR coding style and is considered to be the standard for PHP. As you can see over at [the documentation](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) at 4.1 (functions), it mentions that:

> The opening brace MUST go on its own line, and the closing brace MUST
> go on the next line following the body.

Comment: That is helpful, even if it does not answer the question directly. I'm wish the document gave a summary of why they chose some of these standards. For instance, In `aVeryLongMethodName()` they do not place `{ }` separated at the start of lines. Nor do they do it for closures (eg. `$closureWithArgs`).

I am still interested to know IF customization is available for formatting in VSC, even if you have convinced me it might be worth promoting the standard rather than keeping people in their comforts zone.